# Previously entered values get disappeared in JSF datatable

Tags: jquery, jsf, datatable, jsf-2, richfaces

I am a newbie in JSF. Here's my problem:
I have a data table inside a form in JSF page.

```
     <h:form id="mainForm">
         <rich:dataScroller for="itemDataTable" maxPages="30"/>                                 
         <rich:dataTable rowKeyVar="rkVar" rows="15" id="itemDataTable" value="#{itemsController.itemDM}" var="r">
            <h:column id="setValue">
                <h:inputText id="finalItem" valueChangeListener="#{itemsController.recalculate()}" value="#{r.items.prices}"/>
            </h:column>
            ...
            ...
        <!-- other columns --> 
        </rich:dataTable>
        <rich:dataScroller for="itemDataTable" maxPages="30"/>                                 
    </h:form>
```

I have around 15 pages in my data table. I entered the final values for finalItem in first page and click the next page.Now if i come back to first page, I found that all the previously entered values were disappeared from the data table.
Please help on this and please let me know if i am missing some attributes in the data table. I would also like to know if there is any possibility to handle this from JQuery.
Any assistance will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In rich:dataScroller default value for ajaxSingle attribute is true. You have to make it false explicitly. The problem is your datatable values are not being submitted because of ajaxSingle="true"

Change your data scroller like this

```
     <rich:dataScroller for="itemDataTable" maxPages="30" ajaxSingle="false"/>
```

This should solve your problem.

Please see the tag information of rich:dataScroller here

http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/dataTableScroller.jsf?tab=info&cid=574957

For Richfaces 4.X

See this link for the attributes of rich:datascroller
http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_X/vdldoc/ .

You can use execute attribute to process your datatable on page change.

```
<rich:dataScroller for="itemDataTable" maxPages="30" execute="your datatable id here"/>
```

Comment: I am still getting error as "The attribute ajaxSingle is not defined in the component dataScroller". I am using richfaces 4.3.4.

Comment: Updated the answer with richfaces 4.X also. hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Merge the following line in your dataScroller

**EDITED**

```
 <rich:dataScroller for="itemDataTable" maxPages="30"  execute="itemDataTable"/>
```

and that should do the trick!!

Comment: What is this <a:support>, I dont know the library reference for it.

Comment: a4j m sorry .. i just edited it.. i got a feeling you might get confused.. just use a4j instead of a..

Comment: Sorry again, a4j does not have <a4j:support>, the above tag is showing me the error indicating that it does not have component support.

Comment: pls check whether you have  added a4j taglib in xhtml file

Comment: Yes i did that, This is reference isn't it:  xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"

Comment: The a4j:support has been replaced by a4j:ajax since RichFaces 4.x. so just change it to ajax

Comment: I tried with a4j:ajax also but it showed me " <a4j:ajax> onpagechangeevent is not supported for the UIDataScroller" error. :(.

Comment: I have updated the answer .. after lots of research i found solution.. it is working for me..  let me whether its working for you..

Comment: Tons and Tons of thanks. It worked like a charm. I have a very low reputation so I was unable to give you a upvote. If possible I would have given you 100k upvote. Many many thanks to you. It really solved my problem.